# Extjs Promise with multiple async operations

Tags: javascript, extjs, promise, extjs6

Have an application where we have to perform multiple async operations (saving 2 stores and save one model) before we execute an callback. So only if all of them are successful we execute some specific code. Of course i could do that with nesting callbacks but still the operations would not be async and (since they are nested) and the code becomes ugly. Saw that Promises are a good solution for this problem. Can someone show me a simple example on how to execute multiple save operations with the help of promises. The reject and resolve is set in the callback function of the model/store save method. But i dont understand the whole picture of when and how i should code such a promise. Thanks for helping

Comment: Take a look at the Promise.all() [method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) (or Sencha's version [`Ext.Promise.all`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/classic/Ext.Promise.html#static-method-all)):

> The `Promise.all()` method returns a single `Promise` that resolves when
>   all of the promises in the iterable argument have resolved or when the
>   iterable argument contains no promises. It rejects with the reason of
>   the first promise that rejects.